# add file to SVN repository

Tags: svn

There is a host named hostA at 10.10.10.40 and I log into this host and I vi files and when I am done I type in svn commit -m "explanation" 
 and after wards an email goes out to evarybody telling them what file I changed and how, and the boss who knows that I am working (HURRAAAAYYY!!!!).

Then I log into hostC (10.1.300.80) and go to the directory were the file I changed is, and then I type in 'svn up  and then I see a version number that matches the one on hostA.

Problem is I am on hostB (10.1.300.81) and I have a file that I changed (on hostB ) and my boss wants this file 'version controled' (booooooo!!!) . Like the next time I need to edit the file on hostB I have to do it the same way that I would edit something on hostC .

When I do an ls -ltra on the hostB in the directory where the file I need to change is I do not see a ".svn"

When I do an 'svn up' /production/scr/userStatsWrapper.sh on hostB - I get

```
Skipped '/production/scr/userStatsWrapper.sh'
```

When I try an 'svn add" /production/scr/userStatsWrapper.sh on hostB - I get

```
svn: '/production/fo/scr' is not a working copy
```

how do I add the file from hostB to the repoistory on HostA?

I attempted to import the whole directory of hostB reports to the SVN on hostA with :

```
svn import -m "reports directory from hoatB" /production/reports/     http://10.10.10.40/export/home/capser/SVN/branches/hostBReports 
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://10.10.10.40/export/home/wjohnson/SVN/branches/hostBReports': 200 OK (http://10.10.10.40)
```

But I do not see a hostBReports directory on HostA (where we make SVN edits)

Answer (score 2):

You don't see .svn, so neither your svn does. This means it's really not a working copy. Make an empty folder next to that one and do checkout from the same repository.

Comment: the file on hostB is not in the SVN repository on hostA. HostB is new, and everybody have been doing thier edits right on that host - instead of the preferred method of makeing edits on HostA and then pulling them to hostB.

Comment: I guess i have to push the file from hostB to the svn repository on hostA - so in the future my coworkers can edit hostb files on hostA and pull them down.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, on HostB you have some exported revision, which is not controlled, but there are changes. I hope the revision is not too old, and there are not many changes. If you know the revision on HostB, create a new checkout of the same revision (or HEAD at least), then copy its .svn to your unversioned modified copy. This way you'll get your working base and be able to analyse accumulated changes. Rather difficult part is with deleted files and folders - they will be treated as missing, but I hope you'll manage that.

Comment: noone has ever imported anything on hostB /production/reports to the SVN. everybody is making edits locally on that box. My boss wants me to 'get hostB /production/reports under version control'. he wants everybody to make the edits on hostA and then do an 'svn up' on hostB to load the changes from hostA.

Comment: I want to add the file I changed, actually the whole directory from hostB to the SVN repository on hostA. I need to set up the reports directory on hostB so we would be doing the 'svn commits' on hostA and the 'svn up' on hostB. i want to set it up so we do the changes on hostA and pull the changes from hostA to hostB.